# Get a list of all the editors of a given Wikipedia page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Using Javascript/JQuery, I'm trying to get a list of all the editors of a given Wikipedia page. My current approach feels clumsy and slow, and I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Right now, I'm using the MediaWiki API with action query and property revisions

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Amy_Coney_Barrett&rvlimit=50&rvprop=timestamp%7Cuser%7Ccomment&format=json
```

I then manually scrape the `user` object inside the `revisions` object. The issue is that it's slow to query every available revision since it returns a ton of detail other than just the editor name. Is there a faster way to get a unique list of editors on a Wikipedia page in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique users?

Unless there are other simpler API calls, this is how

```js
const process = data => {
  return [...new Set(Object.values(data.query.pages)[0].revisions.map(rev => rev.user))]
}

// uncomment this on your page

/* fetch("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Amy_Coney_Barrett&rvlimit=50&rvprop=timestamp%7Cuser%7Ccomment&format=json") // calling the API
  .then(response => response.json()) // grabbing the JSON and create an object from it
  .then(data => process(data)); // process that object
*/


console.log(process(data)); // this just shows it in the console
```

```html
<script>
// test data. Remove when you uncomment the FETCH
const data = { "continue": { "rvcontinue": "20201228092417|996732970", "continue": "||" }, "query": { "normalized": [ { "from": "Amy_Coney_Barrett", "to": "Amy Coney Barrett" } ], "pages": { "53992581": { "pageid": 53992581, "ns": 0, "title": "Amy Coney Barrett", "revisions": [ { "user": "Davide King", "timestamp": "2021-01-02T23:12:50Z", "comment": "/* Early oral argument participation */ ce" }, { "user": "Swood100", "timestamp": "2021-01-02T21:30:56Z", "comment": "/* Textualism and originalism */ Restore space between words" }, { "user": "ToBeFree", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T20:38:00Z", "comment": "not that it really matters, but that's neither correct nor having any visible effect on the page" }, { "user": "Tbhotch", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T20:06:10Z", "comment": "Adding {{pp-move-indef}}" }, { "user": "Rich Farmbrough", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T19:16:35Z", "comment": "/* Suspension of habeas corpus */" }, { "user": "ToBeFree", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:47:21Z", "comment": "Adding {{pp-blp}}" }, { "user": "ToBeFree", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:47:20Z", "comment": "Changed protection level for \"[[Amy Coney Barrett]]\": Violations of the [[WP:BLP|biographies of living persons policy]] ([Edit=Require autoconfirmed or confirmed access] (expires 16:47, 1 February 2021 (UTC)) [Move=Require administrator access] (expires 00:34, 26 January 2021 (UTC)))" }, { "user": "ClueBot NG", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:45:01Z", "comment": "Reverting possible vandalism by [[Special:Contribs/76.69.81.193|76.69.81.193]] to version by Biglittlehugesmall65. [[WP:CBFP|Report False Positive?]] Thanks, [[WP:CBNG|ClueBot NG]]. (3857048) (Bot)" }, { "user": "76.69.81.193", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:44:51Z", "comment": "Undid revision 997659065 by [[Special:Contributions/Biglittlehugesmall65|Biglittlehugesmall65]] ([[User talk:Biglittlehugesmall65|talk]])" }, { "user": "Biglittlehugesmall65", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:44:12Z", "comment": "Reverted 1 edit by [[Special:Contributions/76.69.81.193|76.69.81.193]] ([[User talk:76.69.81.193|talk]]) to last revision by Eyer" }, { "user": "76.69.81.193", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:43:49Z", "comment": "Undid revision 997658781 by [[Special:Contributions/Eyer|Eyer]] ([[User talk:Eyer|talk]])" }, { "user": "Eyer", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:42:35Z", "comment": "Reverted 1 edit by [[Special:Contributions/76.69.81.193|76.69.81.193]] ([[User talk:76.69.81.193|talk]]) to last revision by Eyer" }, { "user": "76.69.81.193", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:41:35Z", "comment": "" }, { "user": "Eyer", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:40:13Z", "comment": "ce, capitalization, [[MOS:JOBTITLES]] (modified by \"an\")" }, { "user": "User3749", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:33:59Z", "comment": "Reverted 1 edit by [[Special:Contributions/2605:8D80:681:96FD:1DDD:3E67:126F:2C|2605:8D80:681:96FD:1DDD:3E67:126F:2C]] ([[User talk:2605:8D80:681:96FD:1DDD:3E67:126F:2C|talk]]) to last revision by User3749" }, { "user": "2605:8D80:681:96FD:1DDD:3E67:126F:2C", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:33:24Z", "comment": "Undid revision 997656696 by [[Special:Contributions/User3749|User3749]] ([[User talk:User3749|talk]])" }, { "user": "User3749", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:32:35Z", "comment": "Reverted 1 edit by [[Special:Contributions/2605:8D80:681:96FD:1DDD:3E67:126F:2C|2605:8D80:681:96FD:1DDD:3E67:126F:2C]] ([[User talk:2605:8D80:681:96FD:1DDD:3E67:126F:2C|talk]]) to last revision by CLCStudent" }, { "user": "2605:8D80:681:96FD:1DDD:3E67:126F:2C", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:32:04Z", "comment": "Undid revision 997655513 by [[Special:Contributions/CLCStudent|CLCStudent]] ([[User talk:CLCStudent|talk]])" }, { "user": "CLCStudent", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:27:22Z", "comment": "Reverted 1 edit by [[Special:Contributions/24.114.76.33|24.114.76.33]] ([[User talk:24.114.76.33|talk]]) to last revision by Serols" }, { "user": "24.114.76.33", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:27:15Z", "comment": "Undid revision 997655400 by [[Special:Contributions/Serols|Serols]] ([[User talk:Serols|talk]])" }, { "user": "Serols", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:26:54Z", "comment": "Reverted edits by [[Special:Contributions/24.114.76.33|24.114.76.33]] ([[User talk:24.114.76.33|talk]]) ([[WP:HG|HG]]) (3.4.10)" }, { "user": "24.114.76.33", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:26:42Z", "comment": "Undid revision 997655124 by [[Special:Contributions/Serols|Serols]] ([[User talk:Serols|talk]])" }, { "user": "Serols", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:25:54Z", "comment": "Reverted edits by [[Special:Contributions/24.114.76.33|24.114.76.33]] ([[User talk:24.114.76.33|talk]]) ([[WP:HG|HG]]) (3.4.10)" }, { "user": "24.114.76.33", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:25:32Z", "comment": "Undid revision 997654753 by [[Special:Contributions/Serols|Serols]] ([[User talk:Serols|talk]])" }, { "user": "Serols", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:24:31Z", "comment": "Reverted edits by [[Special:Contributions/24.114.76.33|24.114.76.33]] ([[User talk:24.114.76.33|talk]]) ([[WP:HG|HG]]) (3.4.10)" }, { "user": "24.114.76.33", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:24:12Z", "comment": "Undid revision 997654591 by [[Special:Contributions/Serols|Serols]] ([[User talk:Serols|talk]])" }, { "user": "Serols", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:23:52Z", "comment": "Reverted edits by [[Special:Contributions/24.114.76.33|24.114.76.33]] ([[User talk:24.114.76.33|talk]]) ([[WP:HG|HG]]) (3.4.10)" }, { "user": "24.114.76.33", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:23:10Z", "comment": "Undid revision 997654306 by [[Special:Contributions/Serols|Serols]] ([[User talk:Serols|talk]])" }, { "user": "Serols", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:22:41Z", "comment": "Reverted edits by [[Special:Contributions/24.114.76.33|24.114.76.33]] ([[User talk:24.114.76.33|talk]]) ([[WP:HG|HG]]) (3.4.10)" }, { "user": "24.114.76.33", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2021-01-01T16:22:26Z", "comment": "" }, { "user": "BartocX", "timestamp": "2020-12-31T18:35:10Z", "comment": "" }, { "user": "2603:9001:2501:2B00:E80C:F610:6371:1B43", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2020-12-31T04:27:18Z", "comment": "" }, { "user": "Keith D", "timestamp": "2020-12-30T19:53:39Z", "comment": "/* Second Amendment */ Remove full stop" }, { "user": "Unknown0124", "timestamp": "2020-12-30T16:00:40Z", "comment": "/* Nomination to the Supreme Court */Removing biased statement" }, { "user": "WikiCleanerBot", "timestamp": "2020-12-30T10:35:02Z", "comment": "v2.04b - [[User:WikiCleanerBot#T20|Bot T20 CW#61]] - Fix errors for [[WP:WCW|CW project]] (Reference before punctuation)" }, { "user": "2600:6C51:7580:5564:20AB:1817:61EA:3A25", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2020-12-30T09:45:07Z", "comment": "/* Nomination to the Supreme Court */" }, { "user": "70.172.7.12", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2020-12-30T09:28:09Z", "comment": "" }, { "user": "AlsoWukai", "timestamp": "2020-12-29T23:57:38Z", "comment": "/* First publicly discernible vote as a justice */ ce" }, { "user": "LizardJr8", "timestamp": "2020-12-29T22:38:08Z", "comment": "Reverted edits by [[Special:Contributions/2604:3D09:1F88:4700:BDB7:F5F5:DF11:33A5|2604:3D09:1F88:4700:BDB7:F5F5:DF11:33A5]] ([[User talk:2604:3D09:1F88:4700:BDB7:F5F5:DF11:33A5|talk]]) ([[WP:HG|HG]]) (3.4.10)" }, { "user": "2604:3D09:1F88:4700:BDB7:F5F5:DF11:33A5", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2020-12-29T22:37:39Z", "comment": "" }, { "user": "2604:3D09:1F88:4700:BDB7:F5F5:DF11:33A5", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2020-12-29T22:35:00Z", "comment": "fixed her title<3" }, { "user": "Swood100", "timestamp": "2020-12-29T19:48:04Z", "comment": "/* Personal life */ How Barrett and her husband are able to care for seven children while holding down jobs is relevant." }, { "user": "P3Y229", "timestamp": "2020-12-29T09:44:03Z", "comment": "/* First publicly discernible vote as a justice */ - Added content and sources" }, { "user": "P3Y229", "timestamp": "2020-12-29T09:43:20Z", "comment": "Undid revision 996952623 by [[Special:Contributions/P3Y229|P3Y229]] ([[User talk:P3Y229|talk]]) - Reason: To add a edit summary" }, { "user": "P3Y229", "timestamp": "2020-12-29T09:41:16Z", "comment": "/* First publicly discernible vote as a justice */" }, { "user": "AlsoWukai", "timestamp": "2020-12-29T04:22:08Z", "comment": "ce" }, { "user": "OgamD218", "timestamp": "2020-12-28T16:21:51Z", "comment": "/* Personal life */ an aunt assisting with the childcare of her nieces and nephews in and of itself as presented here does not belong in an encyclopedia" }, { "user": "2600:1700:8C40:2F70:25AE:46DC:8C65:C710", "anon": "", "timestamp": "2020-12-28T16:12:46Z", "comment": "/* U.S. Supreme Court (2020–present) */" }, { "user": "Ashleyyoursmile", "timestamp": "2020-12-28T09:30:32Z", "comment": "Reverted 1 edit by [[Special:Contributions/Editor.angel23|Editor.angel23]] ([[User talk:Editor.angel23|talk]]) to last revision by ClueBot NG" }, { "user": "Editor.angel23", "timestamp": "2020-12-28T09:28:59Z", "comment": "these are just the correct names" } ] } } } };
</script>
```

For example Contributors as pointed out by @Ainali

```js
const process = data => {
  return [...new Set(Object.values(data.query.pages)[0].contributors.map(cont => cont.name))]
}

/* fetch("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=contributors&titles=Amy_Coney_Barrett&rvlimit=50&rvprop=timestamp%7Cuser%7Ccomment&format=json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => process(data));
*/

console.log(process(data))
```

```html
<script>
// test data, remove when you uncomment the FETCH
const data = { "warnings": { "main": { "*": "Unrecognized parameters: rvlimit, rvprop." } }, "continue": { "pccontinue": "53992581|475", "continue": "||" }, "query": { "normalized": [ { "from": "Amy_Coney_Barrett", "to": "Amy Coney Barrett" } ], "pages": { "53992581": { "pageid": 53992581, "ns": 0, "title": "Amy Coney Barrett", "anoncontributors": 121, "contributors": [ { "userid": 124152, "name": "Philip Cross" }, { "userid": 27015025, "name": "InternetArchiveBot" }, { "userid": 7611264, "name": "AnomieBOT" }, { "userid": 24684472, "name": "MusikBot" }, { "userid": 1215485, "name": "Cydebot" }, { "userid": 1763353, "name": "MelanieN" }, { "userid": 279219, "name": "RussBot" }, { "userid": 7903804, "name": "Citation bot" }, { "userid": 237572, "name": "GünniX" }, { "userid": 32005, "name": "Timrollpickering" } ] } } } };
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of prop=revision, go with contributors: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=contributors&titles=Amy_Coney_Barrett&rvlimit=50&rvprop=timestamp%7Cuser%7Ccomment&format=json

Comment: Returning to this, I'm a bit confused how to interpret this code. Where did you retrieve the data in `const data`? And what is the purpose of the commented code? I also notice in the commented code `rvlimit` is set to 50. Does this mean it only retrieves the unique editors from the last 50 edits? What if I want to retrieve ALL unique editors across every edit.

Comment: I took YOUR link with the limit set to whatever it was set to. Investigate the API to see if you can use a higher or no limit. The commented code is what YOU need to use. I commented it out because the question was how to get a specific result from the data. UNCOMMENT the commented code and COMMENT the data variable I used for testing

Comment: `.then(data => process(data));` is processing the data returned from yhe api

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions `rvlimit Limit how many revisions will be returned. 
May only be used with a single page (mode #2).
Type: integer or max
The value must be between 1 and 500.`